# Exact string matching between list and text file data

Tags: python, string-matching

ViolList is a list with elements ['A 230kv','BCD 120kv (after)','yz ckt 1'] and the txt file has lines such as

Description 'BCD 120kv (after)

line1

Description A 230kv - fg 115 kv ckt 2

line 2

Description yz ckt 1

line 3

Description ...

line...

I need to match them exactly such that A 230kv != A 230kv - fg 115 kv ckt 2

```
with open(ContFile.get(), "r") as content_file:
    sectionFound = False
    for line in content_file:
        for x in ViolList:
            x = 'description ' + x
            if x.upper() == line.upper():
                sectionFound = True
                print sectionFound
                break
         if sectionFound == True:
                outfile.write('Found")
```

The below image shows 'line' and 'x' but it still does not return Found:

[image: The below image shows 'line' and 'x' but it still does not return Found]

Answer (score 0):

I think that your problem is that in the lines of your file sometimes have spaces you don't see or need.
It's kind of a guess but you can try to [strip](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/string_strip.htm) your lines, you never know.
So to do that just replace this one:

```
if x.upper() == line.upper():
```

by this one:

```
if x.upper() == line.upper().strip():
```

also it might be a typo but you wrote:

```
outfile.write('Found") # choose one of the quotes
```

finally i just want to point out that with the actual code, if you find a correct line-element match it will constantly keep writing Found for the rest of the list elements, if you don't want that you can also add:

```
sectionFound=False
```

right after writing to your outfile , or replace your existing :

```
sectionFound=False
```

inside the lines iteration, or:

```
break
```

if you don't want to continue the check on other elements of the list.

example of the final thing:

```
with open(ContFile, "r") as content_file:
    for line in content_file:
        sectionFound = False
        for x in ViolList:
            x = 'description ' + x
            if x.upper() == line.upper().strip():
                sectionFound = True
                print sectionFound
                break
        if sectionFound == True:
            outfile.write('Found')
```

Hope that was helpful

Comment: Thanks! That worked. I tried doing the strip earlier but I added the strip to both x.upper() and line.upper(). Is that why that didn't work? Btw there is more to the code once sectionFound is true just shortened it to print for the sake of writing the question. @Rayhane Mama

Comment: Alright you can ignore what i said in the last parts then, but i'll leave them there just for documentation for future users. for that same purpose, if the answer suited your needs perfectly, feel free to accept it ;) and yes it might be a problem, depends on your list @GigI